# JSONDecodeError on response.json() after API GET request on unit test Python

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, mocking

I am struggling with some unit testing on API requests and I am getting this `JSONDecodeError` in my unit test which doesn't make sense to me because the response is content-type `application/json` and it is not empty. At this point I don't have more ideas what is causing that.

My api requests module:

```
import requests
from netrc_auth import netrc_authentication
from config import HOST


client = requests.session()
user, password = netrc_authentication(HOST)

response = client.get(
        f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/info?"
        f"name=test-name",
        auth=(user, password)
    )
response_json = response.json()

if(
    response.status_code == 200
    and response_json["errors"][0]["desc"] == "No such folder!"
  ):
      client.post(
            f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/create?"
            f"name=test-name"
            f"&path={BASE_PATH}/test",
            auth=(user, password),
        )
```

unit tests module:

```
def test_check_folder(monkeypatch, requests_mock, host, credentials):
    client = requests.session()

    if credentials == "":
        monkeypatch.setattr(netrc_authentication, "netrc_authentication", mock_authentication)
        user, password = netrc_authentication(HOST)
        requests_mock.get(
            f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/info?"
            f"name=test-name",
            text="Unauthorized",
            status_code=401,
        )

        response = client.get(
            f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/info?"
            f"name=test-name",
            auth=(user, password)
        )
        assert response.status_code == 401
    else:
        user, password = netrc_authentication(host)

        requests_mock.get(
            f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/info?"
            f"name=test-name",
            text="OK",
            status_code=200,
        )

        response = client.get(
            f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/info?"
            f"name=test-name",
            auth=(user, password)
        )
        response_json = response.json()
        if (
            response.status_code == 200
            and response_json["errors"][0]["desc"]
            == "No such folder!"
        ):
            requests_mock.post(
                f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/create?"
                f"name=test-name"
                f"&path={BASE_PATH}/test",
                auth=(user, password),
                text="OK",
                status_code=201,
            )

            response = client.post(
                f"https://{HOST}:8000/rest/folder/create?"
                f"name=test-name"
                f"&path={BASE_PATH}/test",
                auth=(user, password),
            )
            assert response.status_code == 201
        else:
            assert response.status_code == 200
```

It fails on the part `response_json = response.json()` of the unit test with `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` .Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Have you checked how the response looks before you call `json()`?

Comment: it looks like a json, but i don't know why it doesn't let me get the field `["errors"][0]["desc"]`  like `response["errors"][0]["desc"]` so that is why I am making a `json()` call after I make the request.